# jquery ajax datatable error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am getting this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=discount_html - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

My code is:

```
    $('#abcd').DataTable({  
       "processing":true,  
       "serverSide":true,  
       "destroy" : true,
       "order":[],
       "pageLength": 50,  
       "columnDefs": [
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
        ],
       "ajax":{  
            url: 'abc.php',  
            type:"POST",
            "data": function(d){
                 var frm_data = $('form').serializeArray();
                   $.each(frm_data, function(key, val) {
                     d[val.name] = val.value;
                   });
            },
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                 var return_data = new Array();

                 if(json.data.length > 0){
                    var obj = json.data;
                    console.log(obj);
                    return obj;
                }



                 return return_data;
              }, 
         "columns"    : [
                  {'data':'input'},
                  {'data': 'date'},
                  {'data': 'id'},
                  {'data': 'pname'},
                  {'data': 'cname'},
                  {'data': 'clname'},
                  {'data': 'dname'},
                  {'data': 'act'}
           ]
        },
  });
```

This is my AJAX response:

```
"draw":1,
"recordsTotal":1073,
"recordsFiltered":1073,
"data":[
{
"input":"<input data-id = "0" type="checkbox" name="report[]" class="allCheck" value="1234">",
"date":"2018-01-29",
"id":"1244",
"pname":"XYZ",
"cname":"adasdasd",
"clname":"NA",
"dname":"asdasdasdas",
"act":"hgh"
},
{
"input":"<input data-id = "1" type="checkbox" name="report[]" class="allCheck" value="23232">",
"date":"2018-01-29",
"id":"23232",
"pname":"aaaaa",
"cname":"asdasdsadasdsa",
"clname":"ewqweqewq",
"dname":"aaaaaaaa",
"act":"hgh"
},
```

and below is the HTML:

```
     <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkAll"></th>
        <th class="recept_td01">Date </th>
        <th class="recept_td03">Code</th>
        <th class="recept_td04">Name</th>
        <th class="recept_td05">Ce</th>
        <th class="recept_td05">Cli</th>
        <th class="recept_td06">Doc</th>
        <th class="recept_td07" id="action">Action</th>
     </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong, that I am getting that error, tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Can you include a working fiddle?

Comment: Your error is for `table id=discount_html` but you are showing the Datatable config for `$('#abcd').DataTable({`.  What is the JSON response for the table `discount_html`?

Comment: I'm sort of concerned with your JSON response... it's not valid JSON is all... take a look at your `input`s. It might be worthwhile using single quotes in your serverside script rather than double quotes...?